# If statement within another if statement in Handlebars templates

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, template-engine

These are all objects which I am passing to the handlebars template.

```
self.template = template({ data: self.model, lang:self.lang, page:self.mainPage, subpage:self.param });
```

Then inside foreach loop I have an if statement where I am not able to access the parent context element. The code which i have inside the template and the problem is shown bellow:

```
    {{#each data}}  
        <h1>{{../subpage}}</h1> --> This is giving me a subpage value
        {{#if this.brand}} 

                  {{#if ../subpage}}
                    <h1>WHY IS THIS NOT SHOWING?</h1> --> This is what i am trying to achieve
                  {{/if}}

        {{/if}}  
    {{/each}}
```

Any ideas how to achieve this? Thank you very much for all answers/comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`{{#if this.brand}}` goes down into context another level, so you must escape to the parent context not once, but twice.

Your template should thus be:

```
{{#each data}}  
    <h1>{{../subpage}}</h1>
    {{#if this.brand}} 

        {{#if ../../subpage}}
            <h1>This shows now!</h1>
        {{/if}}

    {{/if}}  
{{/each}}
```

This should work with a `self.model` value similar to:

```
[
    {
        brand: "Brand A",
        otherFields: "here"
    }
]
```

Here is a jsFiddle that demonstrates the solution: [nested if statement context escaping](http://jsfiddle.net/willslab/Y6mXn/3/)

I hope that helps!